# Los Store Procedures siempre reciben parametros?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, store

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me encontre con esta pregunta en un parcial y no supe que responder. Muchas gracias al que pueda ayudarme

Comment: Estuve repasando las clases grabadas pero no encontré nada que me sirviera. Un saludo

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no cumple con los lineamientos del sitio, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. La misma es una pregunta escolar y no plantea ningún tipo de investigación por parte del OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta en el examen está mal planteada. La respuesta correcta es la b, ya que un SP puede recibir o no parámetros.

Al ser opcional el hecho de recibir parámetros, no lo considero como ventaja sino como funcionalidad. No es una ventaja, ya que no tiene comparación directa con algún otro objeto de programación.

Comment: Gracias Juan! Me fuiste de mucha ayuda! Un abrazo grande!